# Prometheus - Database Access

Tags: sql-server, database, prometheus

I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server database via Prometheus. I think I'm supposed to do this using mssql_exporter or sql_exporter but I simply don't know how. I can see the metrics of prometheus itself and use those metrics to build a graph but again, I'm trying to do that with a database. The query doesn't matter, I just need to somehow access a database through prometheus. I've come to this point by watching some tutorials and web searching but I'm afraid I'm stuck at this point. Can anyone help me on this topic. Maybe there is a good tutorial I overlooked or maybe I'm having a hard time understanding the documentation but I would really appreciate some form of help very much. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured how to do what I asked:

1. You want to download Prometheus and the exporter you need.
2. You want to configure your 'exporter.yml' file: In my case, it was the data_source_name variable in the 'sql_exporter.yml' file. By default, it is set to:

   data_source_name: 'sqlserver://prom_user:prom_password@dbserver1.example.com:1433'

So you want to change 'prom_user:prom_password' part to your SQL Server user name and password, 'dbserver1.example.com' part to your server name which is the top name you see on your object explorer in SSMS.

3. After these, you need to let prometheus know about your exporter. Therefore, you need to configure your prometheys.yml file and add a new job. Name it whatever you'd like and write the port of the exporter that it is working on. After you've done that, you can see if it worked through localhost:9090/targets (9090 being the prometheus default port here). If you can see the exporter there, that means this step was successful and you can now see the metrics your exporter is exporting.
4. You can now add prometheus as a data source to grafana and use the metrics you need to  build a dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus scrapes the metrics via HTTP. The exporters take the metrics and expose them in a format, so that prometheus can scrape them.

What you can check:

- is the exporter exporting the metrics (can you reach the `/metrics` page with your browser or curl)
- are there any warnings or  rrors in the logs of the exporter
- is prometheus able to scrape the metrics (open prometheus - status - targets)

Comment: I changed the data_source_name variable in the target section of sql_exporter.yml file and now sql_exporter can export the metrics. That was the first part of what I was trying to do. 2nd part is to make some sort of connection between prometheus and sql_exporter (if I need to do that). The last part is to add prometheus as data source to Grafana and make a dashboard. Any suggestions?